# How Do You Convert a Flux Webclient Get Response to ServerHttpResonse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

in my Spring Cloud Gateway filter, if a certain actions happens in the request flow, we would like to make a HTTP request to another service and return the result as the response. How do I use a Flux Webclient to make a request to a URL and then update the exchange response so when returning it as complete the request result is returned as well?

here is an example of what we are trying to do

```
public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final GatewayFilterChain chain) {
   if (exchange.getHeaders().containsKey("Test")) {
      ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
      String url = "http://localhost:8080/test";
      
      Webclient.create(url).get() // I need to do something more so I can write to the response object
      return response.setComplete();
  }
  return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you read the webflux documentation on webclient?

Comment: yes I did not find what I was looking for but if you have a good link that would be great

Answer (score 0):

it is better to have a deep read in offical documentation for slove confuse , they had many best practices .

for your question

- How to use webclient do a request and return the result as complete for the exchange repsponse
  here is  code snippet

```
@Component
public class MyWebClient {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MyWebClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
    }

    public Mono<ServerHttpResponse> getResponse() {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("https://example.com")
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                        Flux<DataBuffer> responseBody = response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers());
                        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                        headers.addAll(response.headers().asHttpHeaders());
                        ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(responseBody));
                        serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(response.statusCode());
                        serverHttpResponse.getHeaders().addAll(headers);
                        return Mono.just(serverHttpResponse);
                    } else {
                        return response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

in above example , The `exchangeToMono()`  method is used to convert the `ClientResponse`  returned by the WebClient to a Mono that emits a `ServerHttpResponse`. Inside the lambda expression passed to `exchangeToMono()`, the response object represents the ClientResponse returned by the WebClient.
you can use `ServerWebExchange.getResponse()`  instead of ServerHttpResponse ,   both of theirs theory is same;